# How to find volume of substance from molar concentration

Tags: analytical-chemistry, concentration

The concentration of a substance dissolved in water $i$ is known in (mol/m<sup>3</sup>), so is the molar mass in (g/mol) and the density in (g/m<sup>3</sup>).

I want to find the volume of this substance in m<sup>3</sup>.

I have two possible ideas for equations to use:
$$\mathrm{volume}_i= \frac{\mathrm{mass}_i}{c_i  \times M_{W,i}},$$
however, to use this equation I need to know the mass of the substance, which is not obvious.

Also I could use something like this:
$$\mathrm{volume}_i = \frac{c_i \times M_{W,i} \times \mathrm{volume}_{?}}{\rho_i },$$
however, I'm not sure what volume$_?$ would be, as I don't know the volume of the solution and I am trying to find the volume of the substance $i$.

Any ideas how to find the mass in the first equation or the volume in the second equation, or other equations to use?

*Extra comments:*
My real aim is to find the volume of the solution so I can use the following formula for volume concentration, where I already know the volume concentration $\phi_i $:
$$\phi_i = \frac{\mathrm{volume}_i} {\mathrm{volume}_\mathrm{solution}} $$
 or 
$$\mathrm{volume}_\mathrm{solution} = \frac{\mathrm{volume}_i} {\phi_i} $$

Answer (score 1):

Nothing has been said about the actual volume of the solution, only concentration of the solution has been given.

Assume that $c$ moles of solute is present in 1m$^3$ of solution.

Then mass of solute=c*molar mass

volume of solute * density of solute = c* molar mass

From this equation, volume of solute can be known.

*Clearly, if the volume of the solution increases, the volume of the solute will also increase. Since the volume of the solution has not been given, it must give you a hint to take the above assumption.*

Comment: See extra comments in original post. 
Also with my units and your calculation don't I end up with (g)=(g/m^3) if molar mass is in (g/mol). 
Maybe I am asking the impossible

Comment: You have not been given anything about this volume concentration term(in the question) that you made up on your own. You have been given Molarity(the units given are mol/m$^3$)  and you have to use that.

Comment: Also, your volume concentration term in unitless and the concentration term(molarity) given in the question has units mol/m$^3$